# EditText weird cursor position

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

I have implemented an EditText in my app but I have encountered a weird problem where the cursor is not aligned with the marker in the text. As seen in the picture below the blue cursor is not aligned with the blue marker line. How do I fix this and what is the cause?

Image of my problem:

[image: EditText cursor position problem]

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/desc_text"
    style="@style/EditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="start|top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textFilter"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:maxLength="220"
    android:minHeight="85dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/myText"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    tools:text="This is a default description" />
```

Edit: Added layout code, I don't have any java code for the EditText implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
editText1.setSelection(position)
```

Look for this in your code and comment it.
If it doesn't help, share the code.

Comment: Don't have that line anywhere, I've shared my code above.

Comment: I don't have any javacode for the EditText at the moment other than an initial setText() call.